# Registering a process and calling a module function in Erlang

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I'm new to Erlang. I have a Map with which I have to create registered processes of all the keys and then further processing. I'm registering the processes in partone module:

```
-module(partone). 
-import(parttwo,[start/2]).
start() ->
    {ok,List}=file:consult("file.txt"),
    MyMap=maps:from_list(List),
    maps:fold(
        fun(Key,Value,ok) -> 
            print_Map([Key],[Value])
        end,ok,MyMap),
    maps:fold(
        fun(K,V,ok) -> 
            register(K,spawn(calling, startFun,[K,V]))
        end,ok,MyMap).

print_Map(Key,Value)->
    io:fwrite("~n~w : ~w",[Key,Value]).

parttwo.erl:
-module(parttwo).
-export([startFun/2]).
-import(partone,[startFun/0]).

 startFun(Key,Value) ->
    io:fwrite("~w~n KEY::",[Key]).
```

I could get the map contents in the output which is by print_Map. 
But then I'm getting the following error:
{"init terminating in do_boot",{function_clause,[{exchange,'-start/0-fun-1-',[jill,[bob,joe,bob],true],[{file,"d:/exchange.erl"},{line,40}]},{lists,foldl,3,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1263}]},{init,start_em,1,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,1085}]},{init,do_boot,3,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,793}]}]}}
init terminating in do_boot ({function_clause,[{exchange,-start/0-fun-1-,[jill,[*],true],[{*},{*}]},{lists,foldl,3,[{*},{_}]},{init,start_em,1,[{*},{*}]},{init,do_boot,3,[{*},{*}]}]})

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is caused by using `ok` as the 3rd parameter to `maps:fold()`.

In your first call to `maps:fold()`, because `io:fwrite()` returns `ok`, your fun returns `ok` each time it is called, which means erlang makes the call:

```
Fold_Fun(hello, 10, ok)
```

which matches your fun clause:

```
                          |
                          V
Fold_Fun = fun(Key,Value,ok) -> ...
```

However, in your second `maps:fold()` call, because `register()` returns a pid, your fun returns a pid each time it is called, which means erlang makes the call:

```
Fold_Fun(hello, 10, SomePid)
```

which does not match the fun clause:

```
                        a pid
                          |
                          V
Fold_Fun = fun(Key,Value,ok)
```

If you want to ignore the 3rd parameter of `maps:fold()` then you can specify a *don't care variable*, e.g. `_Acc`.  In erlang, a variable will match anything, while the atom `ok` will only match `ok`.

====

```
spawn(calling, startFun,[K,V])
```

You have not posted anything about a "calling" module.

```
-module(my).
-compile(export_all).

start() ->
    {ok, Tuples} = file:consult("data.txt"),
    MyMap = maps:from_list(Tuples),
    io:format("~p~n", [MyMap]),
    Keys = maps:keys(MyMap),
    lists:foreach(
      fun(Key) -> 
            #{Key := Val} = MyMap,
            register(Key, spawn(my, show, [Key, Val]))
      end,
      Keys
    ).

show(Key, Val) ->
    io:format("~w : ~w~n", [Key, Val]).
```

data.txt:

```
~/erlang_programs$ cat data.txt
{hello, 10}.
{world, 20}.
```

In the shell:

```
9> c(my).
my.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,my}

10> my:start().
#{hello => 10,world => 20}
hello : 10
world : 20
ok
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have a constraint to pass the map key and values to another file for processing.

Comment: calling module is 'parttwo' in parttwo.erl

Comment: I'm still getting this error:
=ERROR REPORT==== 19-Jun-2018::14:22:29 ===
Error in process <0.90.0> with exit value:
{undef,[{parttwo,show,[bob,[john]],[]}]}

Comment: @NR9, The error message says that there is no function named `show()` defined in a module named `parttwo`.   You are either getting your module names confused or you made a spelling error.

Comment: *I have a constraint to pass the map key and values to another file for processing*--The code in my example `spawn(my, show, [Key, Val])` can be changed to `spawn(any_other_module, show, [Key, Val])` and erlang will still spawn a new process.

Comment: The other module to which the map values had to be passed was throwing an error and hence could not access the show method (beam file wasn't getting created). Now it's working fine. Thanks for your help @7stud!